# How to coordinate tests in remote machines with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-testing

I am using Jenkins for my build and integration testing.

After build is completed, the build artifacts are deployed into the remote machines. I am using JMeter to perform load testing.

I also need to SSH into the boxes and then I need to run several commands.

I can use Expect command in Linux to Automate this for example, to log on to a remote machine and then to run the commands that I need.

However I have to support both Linux and Windows and I am not sure how I can do this Windows.

Can any one give any suggestions regarding this? Probably some Jenkins plugin can help here?

Comment: Could you run these commands as part of the build?

Comment: I need to run them after the build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate jobs your build and the test.

Control the trigger sequence by with Build Trigger > Build after other project are built.

or

Create another controller job, use [parameterized tirgger pluggin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to control the sequence of your whole execution.

Hope this helps ;D